# Proof of Lamé's theorem in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, elliptic-curves

Apparently, a result of Lamé says the following. Suppose three lines $a$, $b$, $c$ intersect a non-singular cubic curve on points $a_1, a_2, a_3$, $b_1, b_2, b_3$ and $c_1, c_2,c_3$.

If $a_1, b_1,c_1$ are collinear and $a_2,b_2,c_2$ are collinear then so are $a_3, b_3,c_3$.

How can I prove this?

Is there a proof of this that doesn't go through the Cayley-Bacharach theorem (the 8 points -> 9 points result)?

I am aiming to use this fact to derive the associative law for the elliptic curves, so this proof needs to use only elementary things but not the associativity of elliptic curve addition.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234085/help-understanding-geometric-proof-using-cayley-bacharach-that-group-law-on

Comment: The proof there uses the Cayley-Bacharach theorem. https://mathoverflow.net/a/37311 suggests a much simpler proof, at least once you prove the Lame's result mentioned above

Comment: Yes, because you need to use Cayley-Bacharach to prove this, as far as I know. If you wanted a proof without Cayley-Bacharach, you should have said so.

Comment: If you can prove the Lame's theorem from Cayley-Bacharach I'm happy with it

Comment: It's a quick application of Cayley-Bacharach, as seen in the linked answer (ctrl+f "Cayley-Bacharach" if you're having trouble finding it in the post). That's why I suggested it as a duplicate: because the answer there could solve your question.

Answer (score 2):

If we denote [the group operation for elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law) by $+$, then the nine points and three lines we're given correspond to three equations (remember that this operation is commutative):
\begin{equation}
a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 0 \tag{1}
\end{equation}

$$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 0\tag{2}$$

$$c_1 + c_2 + c_3 = 0\tag{3}$$

The antecedents in your theorem statement give us two further equations:

$$a_1 + b_1 + c_1 = 0\tag{4}$$

$$a_2 + b_2 + c_2 = 0\tag{5}$$

---

Add $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$, and subtract $(4)$ and $(5)$. This gives the desired result:

$$a_3 + b_3 + c_3 = 0$$

Comment: In the future, please edit your previous answer instead of posting a new one.

Comment: The previous answer was unsalvageably incorrect, as pointed out by @user10354138. Hopefully this answer is better.

Comment: I meant "replace the text in the other answer", not "salvage the argument".

Comment: Actually, I am trying to prove the associative law of the elliptic curves by using Lame's theorem, so would much prefer a proof that doesn't use EC + associativity